# Bind GridView to List<of class>

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm trying to bind a grid view to a

```
List<Line>
```

where Line is a class with the structure

```
Line.Length
Line.X1Y1.X
Line.X1Y1.Y
...
```

If I do use the binding as follows:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = lines;
```

it's filling the content of Line but not the content of Line.X1Y1, instead it's inserting "Project Name.Form Name -> Sub-class Name" but not it's content as a new column.

How should the invokation of "`lines.Select().ToList();`" should look like to get the Lines-Class content?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use direct `DataSource` can use as follows:

```
 this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
 foreach (Line item in Lines)
 {
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.X1Y1.X, item.X1Y1.Y);
 }
```